# Do flex-shrink/grow/basis not work inside an inline-flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

It seems that flex-shrink / flex-grow / flex-basis do nothing inside an inline-flex container.
Is this the correct behaviour?

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='child1'>
    child1
  </div>
  <div>
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.child1 {
  flex-basis: 500px;
}
```

I would expect the `child1` element to start at 500px if there is space on the screen and shrink to fit on one line if required, but it just matches the width of the content.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r82hukbn/2/

Background:
I want to have a flex container with children that will shrink to fit on one line, but expand up to some maximum width if there is space. I also want the container to only expand up to the maximum width of the child elements, and not fill the whole screen width.

This could be achieved with something like the following css, but it seems like it would be cleaner if I could use inline-flex to make the container fit to the width of its' children and remain on one line while having the children expand and contract as necessary, without having to calculate the max-width to set on the parent.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: **px; // Need to calculate based on the amount of children being displayed
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Give the container a width large enough ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kw6buedz/)) you'll see the flex items adjust; `inline-flex` causes the container to shrink down to the size of its contents. With regards to the problem you're trying to solve, that should be possible without using `inline-flex`, though without context I can't offer a solution right now.

Comment: use width instead of flex-basis